# Changing of index in sum notation

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series

The following is the derivative of the power-series expansion of $e^x$. I can't seem to understand why the starting point changes to $1$ after the second $\text{“}{=}\text{''}.$ Would this surely not be missing out a term?
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac d {dx} \, \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x.
$$

Comment: $\frac{n}{n!} =  \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$, and if $n=0$ then this first term would just disappear.  So we can really just start at $n=1$

Comment: Derivative of a constant term is zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\dfrac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} = 0$ when $n=0,$ so the $n=0$ term of the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}$ can be discarded, yielding $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty$ instead of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty.$

Comment: It's a bit sloppy to do that *and* cancel the $n$ in the same step, IMHO.  If they would've done it as two separate steps, OP might not have been as confused.

Comment: @Kevin True, but proofs are sometimes like spaghetti code - it looks so obvious when laying it down that surely no one would be confused. Upon rereading some time later, the same person might need help to decipher their own logic. :)

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n.$$ Therefore, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n x^{n-1}}{n!} = 0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n x^{n-1}}{n!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The correct form should have been $$\frac d {dx} e^x =\frac d {dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}= 
           \sum_{n=0}^\infty       \frac d {dx} \, \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$$

$$\frac {d}{dx} ( 1+x+x^2/2 + x^3/6+\cdots)= 1+x+x^2/2 + x^3/6+\cdots$$